# Send email from web to server using PHPMailer SMTP protocol

Tags: smtp, phpmailer

Hi I'm newbie here and i have a simple php form and when user submit it the data will be insert in database and email is send to user using PHPMailer; now mine question is that if i send two consecutively emails that have time difference of 1 minute then why their receiving time difference to user is 15 minutes.

Code will be provided on request.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Might be because of server delay are you using a shared server or maybe you mailer is miss confined

Comment: May be shared server cause for it; but if you know how to speed up email processing and how to collapsed processing time then kindly post your answer.